# Как указать "если меняется значение Get, то ..."

Tags: php, функции

Не могу найти функцию, которая бы проверяла изменения переменной. Помогите, пожалуйста.
Суть вопроса в том, что мне нужно проверить, меняет `$_Get['t']` свое значение или нет. Какая функция в `php` проверяет замену переменных?

Comment: Что значит "меняет своё значение"? Когда меняет? Во время выполнения? Между запросами?

Comment: это может быть при замене кода сайта или же в адресной строке!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Делать было нечего :)

```
class GETMonitor {
    protected static $variableKey = NULL;
    protected static $previousValue = NULL;

    public static function tickHandler()
    {
        $currentValue = isset($_GET[self::$variableKey]) 
                      ? $_GET[self::$variableKey] 
                      : NULL;

        if ($currentValue !== self::$previousValue) {
            echo '<hr />changed<hr />'; // делаете свою магию
            self::$previousValue = $currentValue;
        }
    }

    public static function start($key)
    {
        if (self::$variableKey) {
            return;
        }

        self::$variableKey = $key;
        self::$previousValue = isset($_GET[$key]) ? $_GET[$key] : NULL;

        declare(ticks=1);
        register_tick_function(__CLASS__.'::tickHandler');
    }

    public static function stop()
    {
        self::$variableKey = NULL;
        unregister_tick_function(__CLASS__.'::tickHandler');
    }
}
```

Демо:

```
$_GET['someKey'] = 12;
GETMonitor::start('someKey'); // запускаем
echo '2';
echo '3';
$_GET['someKey'] = 18;
echo '4';
echo '5';
$_GET['someKey'] = '18';
```

Всякие другие возможности, слежение за разными значениями разных переменных - дело ваше. Работает, как видно, во время выполнения после вызова `start()`.

Ах, да - оно здорово тормозит работу. На данном примере - в 10 раз :)

**Но если серьезно.**
Этот код стоит применять только в исключительных случаях.

Если переменная будет меняться во время выполнения скрипта (могу только догадываться, что значит "меняется код"), то лучше сделать обращение к ней через сеттер:

```
function setT($value) {/* установка, проверка на изменение, реакция */}
```

Если же между запросами, то сохраняйте где-то предыдущее значение и сравнивайте его при каждом запуске скрипта. Тоже довольно специфичная задача.

Скорее всего, вы себе придумали проблему, но дело ваше.

Comment: для моего мозга сложная штука... я до такого не дорос(( ну все равно спасибо!

Comment: обновил ответ, чтобы хоть немного оправдать слова благодарности :)

Comment: так легко на душе, что я со своей проблемой остаюсь не один, вы даже  не представляете! за это вам благодарен, а за помощь, отдельное спасибо!)
проблема такая, user зарегистрирован, заходит в личный кабинет и в ссылке на данный кабинет стоит GET-переменная, через которую идентифициируется сам пользователь... но при всем этом, просто набрать вместо manager.php?user=21 это manager.php?user=23 (число в конце ссылки), можно легко передвигаться по чужим кабинетам, получает доступ на чужие кабинеты... передо мной стоит задача обеспечить безопасность, но не пойму (не знаю), как...((

Comment: долго думал, как можно пресечь вот этот вариант простой замены переменной GET в ссылке на кабинет, думал, как сравнить, но ничего толком и не придумал...

Comment: Полный бардак. Во-первых, если кто-то зайдёт по ссылке с другим `user=`, то вы никаким образом не отловите "изменение" переменной. А получите в новом скрипте новую копию. Во-вторых, сессии на что?

Comment: Совсем другой вопрос - необходимо сначала проверить, может ли данный пользователь просматривать этот кабинет. Eсли не может - выдаете ошибку (403, например) и завершаете работу.

Как и что сравнивать - зависит от вашей системы, если 21 и 23 это ``id`` пользователя, то их и сравнивайте. Т.е. что-то вроде:

    if ($authorizedUser->id != $_GET['user']) {
        // реакция на доступ к чужому кабинету
    }

С другой стороны, вообще не понятно зачем тогда передавать ``user``, если вначале работы можно определить ``id`` текущего пользователя.

Comment: вот этот бардак и меня беспокоит... я получил id_user за счет запроса в бд, а вот если кто-нибудь просто поменяет значение в ссылке, он легко может попасть к другому в кабинет... по ходу у меня неправильный алгоритм работы самой системы... я никак не могу привязать к пользователю именно этот номер, хотя в бд все записано!

Comment: @tagir, изучите вопрос [регистрации/авторизации на PHP](https://www.google.com.ua/search?q=%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F%20php)